# Secure/Fast Encryption for Symmetric Key after RSA Key Exchange?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, rsa, boost-asio

So I'm working on an ASYNC TCP connection using BOOST Asio in C++ and I'm curious as to what form of encryption would be the fastest while at the same time secure for packet encryption. I've been told that asymmetrical RSA should **ONLY** be used for the initial key exchange. However afterwords, a symmetrical key should be used such as RC4, AES, etc...

I plan on having the server listen on a TCP port, and when the server gets a request from a client it'll send it's RSA 2048 Public Key. The client will generate a random encrypted symmetrical key to use after the RSA exchange. The client will then encrypt that symmetrical key using the server's public key. Then it'll send that encrypted packet to the server for it to be decoded using the server's private key. After that is performed, the RSA encryption will drop and the server/client will communicate over the symmetrical key.

First off, I'd like to know if my proposed method would be the best solution in a high volume server. (I'd like to hold 10,000 active connections at once sending TONS of data)

Secondly, I'd like to know what symmetrical key to use that would be secure but not too slow. At first I was told to use AES-256, however I've read that it's too slow so many people use RC4 or SHA-1. The problem with RC4 and SHA-1 is that they apparently are easily broken.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a standard protocol like TLS? If your server has a modern CPU with AES-NI instructions, the AES-GCM based suites will be extremely fast.

Comment: Wouldn't TLS be too slow for a server encrypting about 5KB/s with 10,000 connections at once? TLS uses AES I believe.

Comment: 50MB/s should pose no problems, you can get 10-50x that much. 10000 RSA handshakes, cost about a minute on one fast CPU core, which is a bit annoying if the they happen at the same time, so I'd consider using the ECDHE_ECDSA handshake instead.

Comment: TLS is a protocol.  AES is a cipher.  The TLS protocol provides cipher negotiation, where a client and server can agree on a cipher.  You can use RC4 with TLS.  Incidentally, [RC4 is broken](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2868725-recommendation-to-disable-rc4.aspx) with TLS.  And people don't use RC4 *or* SHA-1.  They use a cipher suite that includes RC4 *with* SHA-1.    Look, I'll just say it plainly:  if you don't know even these details, you really shouldn't be trying to make your own crypto algorithm.  Play it safe and use TLS 1.2 with AES.

Comment: I knew about RC4 and SHA-1 being broken. I'm just trying to find a nice symmetric algorithm to use that will be fast without vulnerability. I've just heard everywhere that AES is simply too slow. If I'm not mistaken RSA is hard to mess up if you use the pub/priv key correctly. However what I've been told is that the cipher is where people really screw up.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a SSL offloader to me. Don't invent your own protocol; you *will* go wrong.

Comment: I don't the think you'll even need any extra hardware, a moder cpu is plenty fast. Those "AES is too slow" claims are simply outdated, especially on CPUs with AES-NI. Pure AES-GCM should run at more than 1GByte/s on such a CPU.

Comment: @Oatman The problem with SHA1 isn't that its broken, since those attacks don't apply here. The big red flag is the phrase "rc4 or sha1" which indicates you're not familiar with the differences between ciphers, hashes and MACs. Where people screw up is when combining secure primitives into a protocol, which is exactly what you're trying to do. Don't replace TLS, choose a fast ciphersuite within TLS and use a high performance implementation.

Comment: Alright, which cipher suite in TLS 1.2 would you guys recommend that would be fast enough for what I'm mentioning?
I didn't see the one you mentioned on Wikipedia ECDHE_ECDSA.